# How to decrypt token Encrypted with the following codes?

Tags: asp.net-core, encryption, jwt, blazor-webassembly

I have a jwt that is encrypted using these statements:

```
var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));

// Credentials that are encrypted which can only be created by our server using the private key
var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
    var encryptingCredentials = new EncryptingCredentials(
         new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:DecryptionKey"])),
         SecurityAlgorithms.Aes256KW,
         SecurityAlgorithms.Aes256CbcHmacSha512);
    
    
     var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
     JwtSecurityToken token2 = null;
    
     token2 = handler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(
         _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
         _config["Jwt:Audience"],
         new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
         null,
         expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(double.Parse(_config["Jwt:ExpireTime"])),
         null,
         signingCredentials: creds,
         encryptingCredentials);
     
    
     return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token2);
```

my question is how to decrypt returned token manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified part of your codes to make it easeier to be understood:

create token:

```
var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ProEMLh5e_qnzdNUQrqdHPgpsswertxyz"));
var anotherkey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("ProEMLh5e_qnzdNUQrqdHPssqwertxyz"));

// Credentials that are encrypted which can only be created by our server using the private key
var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
var encryptingCredentials = new EncryptingCredentials
    (
     anotherkey,
     SecurityAlgorithms.Aes256KW,
     SecurityAlgorithms.Aes256CbcHmacSha512
     );


var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

var claims = new Claim[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Jhon") };

var token2 = handler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(
    "Issuer",
   "Audience",
    new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
    null,
    expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1),
    null,
    signingCredentials: creds,
    encryptingCredentials);


var jwttoken=new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token2);
```

decrypt,read claims from the token:

```
var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
{
    ValidAudiences = new string[]
    {
       "Audience"
     },
    ValidIssuers = new string[]
    {
       "Issuer"
     },
    IssuerSigningKey = key,

    TokenDecryptionKey = anotherkey
};



var claimsPrincipal = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ValidateToken(jwttoken, tokenValidationParameters, out var securitytoken);
```

It works as expected:

[image]